# Binding DataGridRowHeader button tooltip to row object properties

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridrowheader

I have a button in my `DataGridRowHeader` template that I am positioning on the right-hand side of my columns.

The nice thing about this layout is when you click on the button it doesn't select the row, as it would if you located it in a column.

The issue I'm finding now is that I'm trying to bind the row's object properties, for example in the button's `ToolTip`. It keeps coming back blank, even if I hard-code it in. The same sort of binding on `Visibility` works fine.

How can I fix the ToolTip?

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="btnSelectParent"
                    Template="{StaticResource SelectParentButtonStyle}"
                    Height="15" Width="15" 
                    Margin="0,0,-669,0" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                    Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowSelectParentBtn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}}" >

                <Button.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" 
                               Foreground="Black" 
                               FontWeight="Normal" 
                               Text="{Binding DataContext.ParentBtnMessage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                </Button.ToolTip>

            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridRow` is not a visual ancestor of a `Button` in a `RowHeaderTemplate` but `DataGridRowHeader` is:

```
Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowSelectParentBtn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}}"
```

Your second issue is that the `Tooltip` resides in its own element tree. You could solve this by binding the `Tag` property of the `Button` to the `DataContext` of the `DataGridRowHeader` and then bind to this property using the `PlacementTarget` of the `Tooltip`:

```
<Button x:Name="btnSelectParent"
        ...
        Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}}">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" 
                       Foreground="Black" 
                       FontWeight="Normal" 
                       Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.ParentBtnMessage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: Hi @mm8, unfortunately the ToolTip solution hasn't worked for me. I get the following: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.ChildrenBtnMessage; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='btnSelectChildren'); target property is 'ToolTip' (type 'Object')

Comment: I also checked the Tag property on a click event and it does hold the correct object.

Comment: Did you add the <ToolTip> element as per my sample markup?

Comment: No I had not, works just fine now. I will pay more attention in the future. Thanks for your help